# Python code to print percentage RGB in an ROI not working

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find percentage RGB value of an ROI in camera feed. The end goal is to take a snapshot as soon as an object which has an RGB value of certain threshold arrives in the ROI.
But the code is calculating RGB of entire video feed. Im not able to find out what could be the reason for this, can anyone please help.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cam_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
upper_left = (132, 278)
bottom_right = (586, 400)

while True:
    _, image_frame = cam_capture.read()

    #Rectangle marker
    r = cv2.rectangle(image_frame, upper_left, bottom_right, (100, 50, 200), 5)
    rect_img = image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]]

    sketcher_rect = rect_img
    #sketcher_rect = sketch_transform(sketcher_rect)

    #Conversion for 3 channels to put back on original image (streaming)
    color_B = 0 
    color_G = 0
    color_R = 0
    color_N = 0 # neutral/gray color
    rows=454
    cols=268
    for i in range(132,278):
        for j in range(400,586):
            k = image_frame[i,j]
            #print ("org",k[0],k[1],k[2])
            if k[0] > k[1] and k[0] > k[2]:
                color_B = color_B + 1
                continue
            if k[1] > k[0] and k[1] > k[2]:
                color_G = color_G + 1
                continue        
            if k[2] > k[0] and k[2] > k[1]:
                color_R = color_R + 1
                continue
            color_N = color_N + 1

    pix_total = rows * cols
    print('Blue:', color_B/pix_total, 'Green:', color_G/pix_total, 'Red:',  color_R/pix_total, 'Gray:',  color_N/pix_total)


#Replacing the sketched image on Region of Interest
    image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]] =sketcher_rect
    cv2.imshow("Sketcher ROI", image_frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13:
        break
    
cam_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it..Actually I was entering wrong coordinates in the for loop

```
rows=400-278
cols=586-132
#print (k[0],k[1],k[2])
for i in range(278,400):
    for j in range(132,586):
```